# How to save a file from media storage to firebase storage without using Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, android-intent, permissions

I have a `uri` link in my `firebaseDatabase` stored as:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A6581
```

I need to save this file to `firebaseStorage` giving this link as reference and without the regular `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` pattern.

But i kept getting this error:

```
Process: com.app, PID: 3773
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{3daf6d5d0 3773:com.app/u0a298} (pid=3773, uid=10298) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

I also tried to give it persistable permissions this way:

```
 context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(sourceTreeUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

But i got this error.

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10298 and Uri content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio:6581 [user 0]
```

**Activity**

```
private void chooseAudios() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
          //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Audio"), PICK_AUDIO_FILE);
        }
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_AUDIO_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if(data.getData() != null){
                    Uri fileUri = data.getData();
                    fileName = getFileName(fileUri);
                    fileDuration = getFileDuration(getContext(), fileUri);
                    if (getContext() != null){
                        fileSize = getFileSize(getContext(), fileUri);
                    }
                    DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase = databaseReference.child(userID).push();
                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("title", fileName);
                    map.put("size", fileSize);
                    map.put("time", fileDuration);
                    map.put("status", "queue");
                    map.put("pushKey", Objects.requireNonNull(mFirebaseDatabase.getKey()));
                    map.put("urlString", fileUri.toString());
                    map.put("key1", "");
                    map.put("key2", "");
                    mFirebaseDatabase.setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            updateLayout();
                        } else {
                            updateLayout();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }


    }
```

**Adapter**

```
 @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_audio_draft_item, parent, false);
        mAuth =  FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Podcasts");
        databaseReferenceDraft = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AudioDraft");
        storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AudioDraft audioDraft = postList.get(position);
        String time = audioDraft.getTime();
        String title = audioDraft.getTitle();
        String size = audioDraft.getSize();
        String status = audioDraft.getStatus();
        String key1 = audioDraft.getKey1();
        String key2 = audioDraft.getKey2();
        String uriString = audioDraft.getUrlString();
        String pushKey = audioDraft.getPushKey();
        holder.fileNameView.setText(title);
        holder.fileSizeView.setText(size+" MB");
        holder.fileDurationView.setText(time);
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(firebaseUser!=null){
            user_id  = firebaseUser.getUid();
        }
        databaseReferenceDraft.child(user_id).child(pushKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue(String.class);
                if (status != null && status.equals("download")) {
                    final StorageReference postPath = storageReference.child("Audios").child(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    mUploadTask = (UploadTask) postPath.putFile(Uri.parse(uriString)).addOnProgressListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        //calculating progress percentage
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        //displaying percentage in progress dialog
                       holder.donutProgress.setDonut_progress(String.valueOf(progress));
                    });
                    Task<Uri> urlTask = mUploadTask.continueWithTask(task -> {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                        return postPath.getDownloadUrl();
                    }).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Uri downloadURI = task.getResult();
                            if (downloadURI != null) {
                                downloadUri = downloadURI.toString();
                                Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                map.put("downloadURL", downloadUri);
                                databaseReference.child(user_id).child(key1).child(key2).updateChildren(map).addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    databaseReferenceDraft.child(user_id).child(pushKey).removeValue();
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: provide your source code for this.

Comment: done. pls review

Comment: `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio%3A6581` How did you obtain that content scheme? And where are you using it? Please mark your code with it.

Comment: `But i got this error.` Ok. But where in your code? Which statement causes it? Please mark your code.

Comment: with data.getData(). pls review my updated code again

Comment: That onActivityResult() is called after the user choosed a file. Which ACTION_........  did you use for it to let the user choose? You dont have to show code. Just tell.

Comment: am doing the file intent choosing and firebase storage upload in two separate activities

Comment: file intent choosing? Please be exact. Which Intent.ACTION_......?

Comment: yes. Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT. check my code again

Comment: Ok. now we know how you obtained that uri. But as you have it now you can not use that uri in another activity or the other day. You got read and write permissions for that uri but they do not last long unless to take those permissions permanettly. In onActivityuResult you have to add one statement.

Comment: `context.getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri
        , intent.getFlags() 
               & ( Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION 
               + Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION 
              // + Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
               )
             );`

Comment: Sorry this is not the whole story. Using ACTION_GET_CONTENT you will not get the chance to obtain the read and write permissions permanently. Instead use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: `I also tried to give it persistable permissions this way:` That way was wrong as you cannot grant read and write permissinons yourself. You can only take them and make them permanent if they are offered you. You can see if they are offered you if they are in data.getFlags();

Comment: thanks. it works for me after I change Intent to ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT

Comment: is it necessary I set persistable permissions?

Comment: You will find out yourself soon.